# Knowing programmatically if an app can receive push notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way for an app to know, programmatically, if it can receive push notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially you need to try to register for receiving push notifications.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

If there is possibility you will receive succes delegate method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devTokenLocal
```

And if there is no possibility you will receive failure delegate method. Note that you can analyze error message for more specific info

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{}
```

Comment: after a few more tests I see that this does not cover the following case: 1) the app runs and the user enables push notifications for it. 2) user puts the app to background. 3) user changes device settings turning notifications off for the app. 4) app runs again. Now the app still thinks it can receive notifications. Is there a way to check at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]
```